# Pivot com Tabela Temporária

Tags: sql, pivot

Olá. Estou construindo uma query em que necessito usar pivot para analisar os resultados, porém a mesma não retorna os dados necessários.

Tabela original:

```sql
    select * from tbCampoAdicionalTicket where TCK_SEQUENCIAL = 415945
```

[image: Resultado]

Eu necessito que a coluna CAT_VALOR se torne uma linha unica. Porém encontro alguns problemas na criação do pivot:

1 - A coluna TCK_SEQUENCIAL existe através de chave estrangeira, e não consigo chama-la no select do pivot.

2 - A coluna CAT_VALOR é do tipo VARCHAR e não poderei converte-la pois ocorre casos com texto.

Abaixo, o mais próximo que consegui criar do pivot, mas o resultado retorna uma tabela com todos os valores NULL:

```
SELECT  TCK_SEQUENCIAL, 
        [1] AS CAT_NUMERO_1, 
        [2] AS CAT_NUMERO_2, 
        [3] AS CAT_NUMERO_3, 
        [4] AS CAT_NUMERO_4 
FROM tbCampoAdicionalTicket
PIVOT(
    MAX(CAT_VALOR)
    FOR CAT_NUMERO IN (
    [1],
    [2],
    [3],
    [4])) AS pivot_table
WHERE TCK_SEQUENCIAL = 415948
```

Gostaria de o resultado sair similar a foto, porém com a coluna TCK_SEQUENCIAL junto, pois esta tabela será utilizada em uma procedure:

[image: resultado]

Desde já agradeço a todos!

Comment: Olá viva coloca uma tabela com o resultado esperado, para ficar mais claro.

Comment: Tens [aqui](http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-pivot/) alguns exemplos de PIVOT, verifica se ajuda.

Comment: Ernesto, segue uma imagem melhor exemplificada. A primeira imagem é minha tabela original, a segunda trata-se do pivot, porém preciso agrupa-lo em uma única linha

Comment: Qual [SGDB](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_de_gerenciamento_de_banco_de_dados) esta usando?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ola tens aqui a solução,

```
SELECT  TCK_SEQUENCIAL, [1] AS CAT_NUMERO_1, 
        [2] AS CAT_NUMERO_2, 
        [3] AS CAT_NUMERO_3, 
        [4] AS CAT_NUMERO_4
FROM
(
    SELECT TCK_SEQUENCIAL, CAT_NUMERO, CAT_VALOR
    FROM tbCampoAdicionalTicket
) x
PIVOT(
    MAX(CAT_VALOR)
    FOR CAT_NUMERO IN (
    [1],
    [2],
    [3],
    [4])) AS pivot_table
WHERE TCK_SEQUENCIAL = 415948
```

Comment: Consegui com uma leve modificação na sua observação.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui solucionar a questão através do seguinte script:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT MAX(pivot_table.TCK_SEQUENCIAL) AS TCK_SEQUENCIAL, 
                    MAX([1])                        AS CAT_NUMERO_1, 
                    MAX([2])                        AS CAT_NUMERO_2, 
                    MAX([3])                        AS CAT_NUMERO_3, 
                    MAX([4])                        AS CAT_NUMERO_4,

    FROM tbCampoAdicionalTicket CAT
                    PIVOT(MAX(CAT_VALOR) FOR CAT_NUMERO IN (
                    [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10])) AS pivot_table
```

Comment: A tua solução, funciona, contudo terá um peso na execução superior á minha solução. A base de dados não tendo muitos registos não é critico, se tiver repensa ou revê a tua query. Verifica a execution plan das duas queries no management studio com CRTL + L.